# Selenium Using Python - I couldn't take elements by CSS_SELECTOR

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to select a list of items using a CSS selector. However, when I try to retrieve the elements on the page, I am only getting three items, even though there should be 50 items. After inspecting the page structure, I can confirm that it should contain all 50 elements. Nevertheless, I am still getting a list with only three elements. Is there something wrong with my code or css syntax?

product_names must be an iterable object with 50 items

```
product_names = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".elements-title-normal")
time.sleep(1)
list1 = [] 
for i in product_names:
    list1.append(i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".elements-title-normal.one-line").text())
    time.sleep(1)
print(list1)
```

I got 3 items from "product_names"

Comment: And what would be the url of that page?

Answer (score 1):

To extract and print the texts ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".elements-title-normal .elements-title-normal.one-line")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='lements-title-normal']//*[@class='elements-title-normal one-line']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)